# Cannot add appengine app to google apps primary domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-apps

I created an app engine app (deployed and working) that I want to add to my google apps primary domain.
I followed the directions in the app engine console (going through Administration -> Add Domain).
I typed my domain in and get to the page with the terms and services.
the page has the title: 
You have requested that the ' YOUR_APP_ENGINE_SERVICE_HERE ' service be added to your domain
the url is https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?appId=YOUR_APP_ENGINE_SERVICE_HERE&chromeless=1#OGX:AddAppEngineService

I check the checkbox to accept the terms and services then click activate, after a few seconds I get back to the same terms and services page.
I get no errors that tell me anything.

If this helps my google apps account is one of the grandfathered free accounts (< 10 users).

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app administration on App Engine, not a programming question. You should probably ask this question on App Engine forum.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the forum points to here for appengine support

Comment: Support for programming-related issues and questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a conflict with a google sites website id being the same as the appengine id (eventhough they were going to be into different subdomains). it created a conflict without error messages, so deleting the old site id did the trick